# How to make an alias for a Sass mixin with multiple arguments?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

Since I couldn't find a Question for this specific problem, I will post the solution I came up with.

I want to create an alias for a Sass mixin which has multiple arguments (partially optional ones).

```
@mixin box(
    $width,
    $height,
    $background-color: transparent
) {
    width: $width;
    height: $height;
    background-color: $background-color;
}
```

For this mixin I want to create an alias which just takes all arguments given and passes them through to the original mixin:

```
@mixin box_alias(
    $width,
    $height,
    $background-color: transparent
) {
    @include box( $width, $height, $background-color );
}
```

It feels very redundant to keep listing all arguments again, this totally works agains the DRY principle. So I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Sass you have the possibility to allow a mixin (or function) to have an [arbitrary number of arguments](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function#taking-arbitrary-arguments). To do this you make the last argument an [argument list](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists#argument-lists) by appending three dots (`...`) to its definition. If there is only one argument and it ends with the three dots, then the resulting arument list will contain all arguments passed to the mixin. This works very similar to the spread operator in ES2015.

The resulting argument can be passed on to original mixin, adding the three dots again to unfold them as separate arguments for the call:

```
@mixin box_alias($arguments...) {
    @include box($arguments...);
}
```

This works well for positional and keyword arguments (even in combination) and also for optional arguments.